# android ACTION_SEND image and text

Tags: android, facebook, image, post, text

I want from my application to send to facebook and other applications an Image and some text so the user can share them. Currently I put the text and the image URI but when I choose facebook only the image is sent. In whatsApp also only the image is sent. In Google+ application both image and text are passed. Can someone show me the right direction?

Code example ( I don't have the original code here with me now, maybe I'll post it later)

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , myText);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app" ));
```

If I change ACTION_SEND to ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE then it does not work at all. If I change type to "text/plain" or html then text is sent to whatsapp, google+ and Facebook messenger, but NOT in normal Facebook app ( it  opens an empty share dialog).

Answer (score 0):

You should use below lines

```
           Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("image/*");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My image");
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filename_toshare)));// this is for image . here filename_toshare is your file path.
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Image ");// this is for text
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: This code means that by adding "EXTRA_SUBJECT" , my "EXTRA_TEXT" will be sent too?  Because I don't see any other actually difference between your code and mine.

Comment: actually in facebook you cannot send any text from app via action send or actionsend multiple because this is the known bug in facebook. but you can send the text to twitter , g+,gmail and all. thats depend upon the apps .. like whats app also doesnt allowing us to send the text from our app. we need to type over there.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Maybe direct use of the facebook Graph API?